# How to insert norman date in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm  totally new to php and mysql & need some help with this.
I want to insert a date into a mysql table, formatted as dd/mm/yyyy.

I have 4 columns in my table: id, name, age & birthday.

MY HTML-CODE

```
<form action="php_creat_cliente.php" method="post">
Name     : <input name="reference" type="text" /><br />
Age      : <input name="focode" type="text" /><br /> 
Birthday : <input name="date" type="text" /><br />
</form>
```

MY PHP-CODE

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$birthday=$_POST['birthday'];

$save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO loan (name, age, birthday) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$birthday')");

header("location: index.html");
exit();
?>
```

Currently, the date is inserted in the mm/dd/yyyy format, but I need it in the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: You do not want to store your dates as strings. If you do you will end of in date math hell as you lose all of MySQL's date functionality without having to jump through annoying hoops to get them to work. Store them in a standard format and convert them when you select them from the database.

Comment: you should use jquery datepicker on 'date' text field. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ 
There you can change date format as per your requirement

Comment: @TBI you should not rely on a client-side solution only.

Comment: @TBI thanks for your rply . you mean when i'll select the date in date picker that time i'll se like mm/dd/yyyy . but it'll insert in mysql as like yyyy/mm/dd ???

Comment: You should note that your script is "SQL injection ready"

Comment: @Brewal if we dont use datepicker, javascript validation needs to add which is also client side.

Comment: @UDAY you need to change the date format in datepicker jquery. Its up to you, which format you need.

Comment: Anyway, start by not using `mysql_` functions (`mysqli_` or `PDO` instead) and use prepared statements or at least some input filtering to prevent this massive SQL injection capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL accepts a string in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'yyyymmdd' for dates. So you can enter it in the text field in whichever format you want as long as you make sure you reformat it (in your code) to a valid format (like the ones I mentioned) before passing it to the database.

Or you can specify the format yourself like so:

```
$save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO loan (name, age, birthday) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$age', STR_TO_DATE('$birthday', '%d-%m-%Y'))");
```

The [jQuery UI Datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is popular for dates in forms.

As others have mentioned the current way you're doing this (at least the way shown here) is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), and everything in between. I'd advise you to learn about these attacks if you are to become a web developer.

EDIT:

What jQuery UI Datepicker helps with is picking a date and placing it in the text field in a valid date format. You can specify the format in which you want the widget to show your date like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
```

And then you can make sure MySQL accepts the date format you're submitting in your insert command by specifying it like I showed above:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$birthday', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: WHad you think should i use STR_TO_DATE or i should use Jquery Datepicker . and IF i use datepicker then when i'll see the form, ll'i see date like dd/mm/yyyy but it'll insert like yyyy/mm/dd ??

Comment: Thank you so much man . i did it. hey but how i show result form mysql date to normal date ??? can ya tell mee plz man .

Comment: @UDAY By 'show' do you mean reformat and echo or something? If so, you can do it like this: (1) `$datetime = strtotime($timeFromMysql);` (2) `$newFormat = date('Y-m-d', $datetime);` (3) `echo $newFormat;`. If you were thinking of something else let me know.

Comment: '$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT account_no, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datecolumn FROM savings
WHERE (`account_no` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());'

byt this i can get data from mysql to my page but the problem is that i have to write every column name , so can you tell me how i can use * form table name with the DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datecolumn syntax

Comment: @UDAY You have to specify the column name if you have a function that affects it. So  you can use * to select all the columns that are not affected by functions and then specify the columns with functions affecting them. Like so: `SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datecolumn FROM ...`. By the way, you don't need the parentheses after your `WHERE` clause - `WHERE account_no LIKE '%".$query."%'`.

Comment: @ Alternatex . yea i found this somewhere just a few mints ago , anyway thanks a lot man , really thank ya so much . with your help i just did something and em really happy . thanks a lot man thank you .

Comment: hey facing another problem , actually i have a search form , and it's working , but the problem is that , when i search by 1 then the result come 1 and 10 i mean all data where id is related 1 , like 1, 10 etc . so how can i solve this problem .

Comment: @UDAY Can you show me the SQL query you're using for your search?

Comment: now my code is working fine , i get whad i want , anyway thanks , this is my new code 
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1
            WHERE id=".$query) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways, but the best if you are inserted as date or timestamp.

The first way is, if you store it in a varchar field, but in this case you can not use the [mysql date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Insert in regular way: YYYY-MM-DD

And, when you need it, you can use the mysql date functions to format it, or you can format it with php code also.

If you are assuming, your `$_POST['birthday'];` comes in mm-dd-yyyy format, then you should do something like this

```
//This varaible will come from the form, this is just a test now!
$_POST["birthday"] = 'mm-dd-yyyy';

$month = substr($_POST["birthday"], 0, 2);
$day = substr($_POST["birthday"], 3, 2);
$year = substr($_POST["birthday"], 6);
$birthday = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO loan (`name`, `age`, `birthday`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$age."','".$birthday."')");
```